# wastewater utility web app

Tags: maintenance

I'm trying to create a web-based GIS wastewater utility application integrated with with some maintenance system in the same interface so that for example any problem in the wastewater utility network can be located and a work order will be created for this problem. How can I start creating such an application and what tools do I need? 
thanks

Comment: I tried googling "wastewater web gis" and got lots of hits - perhaps you can do the same and focus your question on whichever option looks most likely to meet your requirements.